# Connecting spread tables to one - schema

Tags: database, database-connection, database-schema

I have tables (its a schema): Factory, Storehouse, Store. And I hire employees in every place (Workers, Cleaners, Sellers), I would like to add them a Social Security Number, so I create new table "Emplo" with field "Social Security num" and I have no idea how to assign to every employee ONE social number. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact syntax depends on your dbms. Nothing can protect you from entering the same person twice with two different id numbers and two different SSANs.

```
create table employees (
  employee_id integer primary key,
  employee_full_name varchar(35) not null,
  employee_ssan char(11) not null unique
);
```

The primary key constraint gives you **one SSAN per employee ID number**. Names aren't unique; you can't have one SSAN per name except in very small applications.

The UNIQUE constraint on employee_ssan guarantees that no two employees have the same SSAN. A few applications *have* to allow duplicate SSANs, but your's probably isn't one of them.

Comment: It's Microsoft Visio Diagram, and I am wondering how to assign table Emplo (with Social Number) to every employee which are in 3 different tables.

Comment: Employees shouldn't *be* in three different tables. The fact that a particular person is an employee is one thing. The fact that a particular employee is currently supposed to work at the factory is quite another. One table for employees; another table for their currently assigned location.